# (OctoKit.ObjC) `.a` libraries for OctoKit, AFNetworking, and ISO8601DateFormatter

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

I am attempting to use, as well as update the extremely outdated (XCode 4!) documentation for, the [Objective-C OctoKit library](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.objc).

In the instructions for importing into a project, step 4 states:

> On iOS, add the `.a` libraries for OctoKit, AFNetworking, and ISO8601DateFormatter.

I started with XCode 6, so much of the information in the `Readme.md` is Greek to me. I've worked through all of it, though, and updated the instructions appropriately, except for this line.

In the "Choose Frameworks and Libraries to add" dialog box in XCode, none of the OctoKit `.framework` or `.a` archives are present. Even looking through the repository in Finder with Hidden Files shown, and using the Finder search bar (which worked for a previous step that called for AWOL files out of their place) returns nil for any frameworks or archives in any of the project files.

Does anyone have an answer for this? I'm not sure if this step was obsoleted, or perhaps I'm not understanding how to search for / locate these types of files.

Any information is greatly appreciated,
Cheers!

EDIT: By adding all the OctoKit `.xcodeproj` files to the workspace in XCode directly, the `.framework` files are now selectable from the Frameworks and Libraries menus, however still nothing for the `.a` files.

Comment: What are the files that you actually have on your disk? It sounds like you just have the projects, without the built products.

Comment: I cloned the repository, then ran the bootstrapper from the script folder, as it states in step 2 with `script/bootstrap` . I am unaware of any additional files or how I would get them.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't looked at the actual material before commenting. It appears that the various projects: OctoKit, etc. don't have static libraries as build products at all. If that's the case, the frameworks should be all that you need. In other words, I believe that you can just ignore the part about the static libraries (.a's).